# Remove small not connected blobs in opencv

Tags: opencv, python

I've got the image:
[image]

I'd like to remove small blobs like these (not all of them are specified):
[image]

Median and erosion don't suit me cause they also destroy needed edges (line-like).
My idea is to move sliding window of specified size and check whether there's a contour(blob) which does not touch window borders that is it fits completely into this window and needs to be removed.

Is there any algorithm which suits me or I have to implement aforementioned idea (but this is probable not supposed to be optimized implemented by me)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we found the contours we can just circumscribe every contour by rectangle by `cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)` command and then check whether width and height of the rectangle is more than our minimum-contour-size.
All contours (yellow edges) are circumscribed by red rectangles.
[image]

The same image but excluding contours which circumscribed rectangle sides less than specified threshold:
[image]

Comment: Instead of cv2.minAreaRect(cnt) cv2.boundingRect(cnt) can be used